# how to check whether "knownlanguages" key contains value ="English" from json datatype of mysql using query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

```
{
  "Actor": {
    "knownlanguages": [
      "English"
    ]
  }
}
```

This JSON is stored in JSON columntype of MySQL with name `data`.

My question is how to check whether `knownlanguages` key contains value `English` from JSON datatype of MySQL using query?

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(json, '"English"', "$.Actor.knownlanguages")
```

or (depending on what you have to do):

```
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(json, '"English"', "$.Actor.knownlanguages") FROM table
```

reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

Answer (score -1):

you can use `like` keyword with wildcard `%`

```
SELECT * FROM table where data like "%English%"
```

**NOTE:**

this won't search in JSON field `knownlanguages`, but in column `data`

Comment: but if data is like {"Actor": { "knownlanguages": ["French"]},"favourite":["English"]} and i want to know the data with "knownlanguages":"[English]"